# In Algebra 1, why is Inverse Variation, categorized as a non-linear function?

Tags: functions, inverse

As far as I've learnt, non-linear functions have to be of a degree greater than 1 (i.e, x^2, x^3, etc). However, an inverse variation problem, usually is in the form: `y = k/x`, where k is our constant. A function, in this form, still gives us a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T4p7.gif)  like the one demonstrated, even with a degree of 1.

I know this is a pretty basic question, but I don't really understand why this happens.

Thank you for any help.

AB6

Comment: The degree is not $1$, but rather $-1$. That is to say, $\frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, how do you define linear function? I'm guessing your definition will boil down to a function of the form $f(x) = ax + b$. $y = k/x$ is not of that form.